# Conditional unchecking of checkbox using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a simple function that tests a condition on a database when a checkbox is clicked, and either allows it to be checked or forces it unchecked. I've included a condition within the jQuery that bypasses this condition if it is being unchecked (as the user should always be allowed to uncheck it).

Using `console.log` to determine what is going on when being executed, everything is working as expected **except** that is does not uncheck the box. It seems the `$('#oncall').prop('checked', false);` simply doesn't do anything.

```
    $(document).on('click','#oncall',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'includes/oncall.ajax.php',
                type: "POST",
                data: {'sheet_date':$('#sheet_date').val()},
                success: function(data) {
                  if (data == 1) {
                    $('#oncall').prop('checked',true);
                  } else {
                    $('#oncall').prop('checked', false);
                  }
                },
                error: function() {
                  alert("Something went wrong.");
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('#oncall').prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
```

The HTML that's applicable is a simple checkbox;

```
<label for="oncall" class="onlab"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="oncall" class="oncall_box" id="oncall"><span class="oncall_label">On call</span></label>
```

It works to activate the checkbox (providing the database condition is fulfilled) but not the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After about an hour, I found what the problem was.

`e.preventDefault();` prevented the checkbox from switching state, which meant the logic in the condition was reversed - the checkbox wasn't checked as soon as it was clicked.

I corrected for this problem by changing the if condition to

```
if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = 0;//if data = 1 it will check
$('#oncall').prop('checked',data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="oncall" class="onlab"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="oncall" class="oncall_box" id="oncall"><span class="oncall_label">On call</span></label>
```

Use like this

Comment: Thanks for trying, but this wasn't it. I realised what the problem was, I had `e.preventDefault();` which means the logic for the condition was reverse (because it prevents the checkbox from switching state). All I needed was an `!` at the beginning of the `if`.